# Tables: - missing counter(number)

Tags: tables

I generated table using [this website](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/). When I compile the pdf I get table without any sort of description. I don't need to have caption. How can I achieve that? I don't know how to google it...I found question with different problems.

Comment: your question isn't very clear but perhaps you just want to add `\caption{}` before `\begin{tabular}` or after `\end{tabular}` it is the caption command that increments the counter and prints the number

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah yes, I tried it and it does what I needed. I'm sorry It is hard for me to express myself clearly in English. If you write it as the answer I would accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you just want to add `\caption{}` before `\begin{tabular}` or after `\end{tabular}` it is the caption command that increments the counter and prints the number.